# Mean value theorem for sums

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I need to prove that if $f$ is continuous in $[x_1,x_2]$ and $a_1$ and $a_2$ are both greater than $0$ then there exists one $y \in [x_1,x_2]$ s.t.

$$a_1\cdot f(x_1) + a_2\cdot f(x_2) = (a_1+a_2)f(y)$$

I have tried using the MVT but I got nowhere. Note that there are no derivatives or integrations in the equation.

Comment: Don't you confuse $IVT$ and $MVT$ ?

Comment: Maybe, i called it mean value theorem for sums because thats how my teacher called it. But i still cant prove it.

Comment: sounds like a homework

Comment: Not really!! Its a theorem my teacher used to prove another result but she never proved the theorem itself and i was trying (unsuccessfully) prove it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the point here is that you can use IVT (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem ) such as follows:

If $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ then it is trivial -- just choose $y=x_1$. Next, WLOG $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$.

Observe that $\lambda_1:=\frac{a_1}{a_1+a_2}$ and $\lambda_2:=\frac{a_2}{a_1+a_2}$ are both constants in $[0,1]$. Then, a number $u:=\lambda_1f(x_1) + \lambda_2f(x_2) \in [f(x_1), f(x_2)]$. Why? Because it is a convex combination, obviously $\lambda_1f(x_1) + \lambda_2f(x_2)\geq \lambda_1f(x_1) + \lambda_2f(x_1) = f(x_1)$ and similarly for the other direction.

From the IVT theorem therefore exists $c$ such that $f(c)=u$, what you wanted to find. (I used the same notation as in wiki page, you have $y=c$).